# Is this a bug in how Clang implements __builtin_memcmp?

Tags: c++, clang, llvm

Ok, so here is the code:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdint>

template<typename T>
[[nodiscard]] constexpr bool
run_tests() noexcept
{
    T const blah1[6]{4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42};
    T const blah2[6]{4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42};
    T const blah3[6]{};

    if (__builtin_memcmp(blah1, blah2, 6 * sizeof(T)) != 0) {
        return false;
    }

    if (__builtin_memcmp(blah1, blah3, 6 * sizeof(T)) == 0) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

int
main() noexcept
{
    static_assert(run_tests<int8_t>());
    // static_assert(run_tests<int64_t>());

    if (run_tests<int8_t>()) {
        printf("success\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("failure\n");
    }

    if (run_tests<int64_t>()) {
        printf("success\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("failure\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

With Clang 10 (on Windows), this compiles fine, and if I run it, I get:

```
success
success
```

As I would expect. If I uncomment the following:

```
static_assert(run_tests<int64_t>());
```

I get the following compile-time error:

```
error: static_assert expression is not an integral constant expression
```

There are two things strange here. The first is that this compiles fine with `int8_t` and `uint8_t`, but any other integer type that I provide it reproduces the error above. Secondly, if I comment out this:

```
if (__builtin_memcmp(blah1, blah3, 6 * sizeof(T)) == 0) {
    return false;
}
```

It compiles fine as well with all integer types. So it is only the case where the arrays are not equal and are not 8-bit that I get this compile-time error.

Thoughts? This seems like a bug to me, but I wanted to see what others thought before I filed a bug report. For reference, I have tried compiling with both C++17 and C++20 enabled, and I have verified that Clang 10 implements __builtin_memcmp as a constexpr (both using the __has macro and by the fact that it compiles fine as a constexpr in some scenarios).

Comment: What documentation leads you to believe `__builtin_memcmp` should ever be a constant expression?

Comment: https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#builtin-functions

Comment: This is a better link: https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#string-builtins

Comment: I'm not seeing anything in that link that the result of `__builtin_memcmp` is a constant expression.  It requires a constant expression in, but that's all I see.

Comment: Its used heavily Libc++ to support constexpr functions. For example: https://github.com/llvm-mirror/libcxx/blob/4428baf8bd0d75bc50be92547edc092879e63e7c/include/__string#L242

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not technically a bug. It isn't documented under what conditions `__builtin_memcmp` is constexpr.

Note that the other answer with the note "read of dereferenced one-past-the-end pointer is not allowed in a constant expression" is from an old version of clang for which `__builtin_memcmp` follows different rules.

The reality appears to be that `__builtin_memcmp` in clang 10 is constexpr if the following conditions are satisfied:

- the length provided is `0` *or*
- the types are integral *and*

  - the size of both types is 1 *or*
  - the answer is 0, i.e., enough elements compare equal

Ordering non-equal multibyte types involves endianness, which involves considering the target architecture which may be different than the host architecture. That does not seem like it was tackled in the current version.

This addresses both observations:

- this compiles fine with `int8_t` and `uint8_t` - because they have size 1
- if I comment out this (the `!=`) - because equality is constexpr

ref: https://reviews.llvm.org/D55510

Comment: This makes sense, although I will say that they either need to address this issue or update the documentation as it was really misleading.

Answer (score 1):

Not a real answer, but hard to put compiler error messages in a comment.  May assist you

With clang version 9.0.1, I see the same behavior.

With an older version of appleClang (Apple LLVM version 10.0.0 (clang-1000.11.45.5)) I get this, even if I comment out the `blah3` stuff...

```
z.cpp:27:19: error: static_assert expression is not an integral constant expression
    static_assert(run_tests<int64_t>());
                  ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
z.cpp:12:9: note: read of dereferenced one-past-the-end pointer is not allowed in a constant expression
    if (__builtin_memcmp(blah1, blah2, 6 * sizeof(T)) != 0) {
        ^
z.cpp:27:19: note: in call to 'run_tests()'
    static_assert(run_tests<int64_t>());
                  ^
1 error generated.
```

Also, I looked, and libc++ uses it here, so I think your assumptions based on the documentation are correct.

```cpp
inline _LIBCPP_CONSTEXPR_AFTER_CXX14
int
char_traits<char>::compare(const char_type* __s1, const char_type* __s2, size_t __n) _NOEXCEPT
{
    if (__n == 0)
        return 0;
#if __has_feature(cxx_constexpr_string_builtins)
    return __builtin_memcmp(__s1, __s2, __n);
#elif _LIBCPP_STD_VER <= 14
    return memcmp(__s1, __s2, __n);
#else
    for (; __n; --__n, ++__s1, ++__s2)
    {
        if (lt(*__s1, *__s2))
            return -1;
        if (lt(*__s2, *__s1))
            return 1;
    }
    return 0;
#endif
}
```

FWIW, I added this to the example...

```cpp
static_assert(__has_feature(cxx_constexpr_string_builtins));
```

Comment: Interesting. I think this is enough evidence for me to file this a bug and see what happens.